# Smooth a mesh after knife/bisect tool

Tags: knife-tool, smooth, sculpt-mode, bisect

I am new to Blender. I got a model from Kaedim/MidJourney, it had a kink, and I wanted to remove it. I tried the knife and bisect tools and they both work. The knived face looks ugly and I want to smooth it:

[image]

[image]

I tried running [triangle fill](https://blenderartists.org/t/triangle-fill-addon-update-for-blender-2-80/1159810) and couldn't get it to work. I also tried sculpting with [the smooth sculpt tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tools.html), but the result is uglier than the original.

How can I smooth that slice so it looks a bit similar to the rest of the mesh?

### update

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0jx5s5dtzvuyg56/ginja%204.blend?dl=0) is the file, a proprietary puppet that I have a license to use.

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file?

Comment: Sorry i can't find the link to the file

Comment: @moonboots My bad, I fixed it now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe you should first convert your tris to quads (Alt J). After that, you could symmetrize the mesh (Mesh > Symmetrize)? Or use the Mirror modifier when you model your character...

Comment: Symmetrizing could be the answer. My first pass gets rid of crude bisection on the right side, but multiplies the three crude bisections on the left side. Could I slide the model around the pivot point of symmetrizing to symmetrize left to right on the lower half, and right to left on the upper half? I didn't model the character, I got it from Kaedim/MidJourney.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear out that hideous automated face, to make a hole, and rebuild the topology by hand. Connect two vertices and press F to join them (creates an edge). Which two vertices to select? Well, just follow the lines. Then after you've connected the vertices in one direction, fill all triangles with faces. Then, connect the vertices in the other direction, this time using J. Then merge the very close vertices, in the intersections that the joining (J) operation created, and then move some verts around, selecting one vert at a time and pressing "g" twice, to move the selected vertice along the edges - this is to even out the triangles.

And then turn off auto smooth!

[image: manual connections]

[image: auto smooth]

It's not the perfect result, but it took me like 5 minutes. You can spend more time adjusting each vert (with Auto-Smooth turned back on), and then maybe smooth in Sculpt, or use a Shrinkwrap from a piece of the other leg, scaled by -1.

[.blend[updated]](https://file.io/BGdoDsG17MnM)

Comment: Thank you! I checked the result and it does what I want. I tried following the steps and I couldn't replicate them (I'm new to Blender). Can you please add details on each of the steps, e.g. a a video tutorial or a section of the manual?

Comment: https://youtu.be/4nXKdAu7va0 - when i grab a vertex and merge it with another i'm using "snap to vertex" and "auto merge"  (i enable auto-merge with the keyboard shortcut "ctrl", after using "g" to move the vertex around) - you can also grab 3 very close vertices and press "m" to merge the 3. hope this helps - i advise you to also look into other videos on how to merge vertices and create faces, basically getting a easier understanding how to do things in blender.

Comment: Thanks! I watched the video, which has all the steps I needed, reproduced them, and now have an OK puppet to play with in Blender.